# Apache Axis unable to instantiate implementation LogFactory in WildFly 11

Tags: logging, wildfly, axis

I'm struggling trying to get an old Java web application built under Hibernate + CDI + Vraptor MVC framework to work.

The app is deployed as an EAR on Wildfly 11. The archive contains a WAR file with JARs like commons-logging.

Could someone provide a hint? Regards.

---

### Error log

```
org.jboss.weld.core//org.jboss.weld.injection.StaticMethodInjectionPoint.invoke(StaticMethodInjectionPoint.java:88)
    ... 102 more
Caused by: org.apache.commons.discovery.DiscoveryException: Unable to instantiate implementation class for org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory
```

---

```
java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException
    at org.jboss.logmanager.commons.logging//org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory.getClassLoader(LogFactory.java:401)
    at deployment.kliftEAR.ear.klift.war//org.apache.commons.logging.impl.LogFactoryImpl.getClassLoader(LogFactoryImpl.java:447)
    at deployment.kliftEAR.ear.klift.war//org.apache.commons.logging.impl.LogFactoryImpl.initDiagnostics(LogFactoryImpl.java:476)
    at deployment.kliftEAR.ear.klift.war//org.apache.commons.logging.impl.LogFactoryImpl.(LogFactoryImpl.java:95)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at deployment.kliftEAR.ear.klift.war//org.apache.commons.discovery.tools.ClassUtils.newInstance(ClassUtils.java:157)
    at deployment.kliftEAR.ear.klift.war//org.apache.commons.discovery.tools.SPInterface.newInstance(SPInterface.java:197)
    at deployment.kliftEAR.ear.klift.war//org.apache.commons.discovery.tools.DiscoverClass.newInstance(DiscoverClass.java:579)
    at deployment.kliftEAR.ear.klift.war//org.apache.commons.discovery.tools.DiscoverSingleton.find(DiscoverSingleton.java:418)
    at deployment.kliftEAR.ear.klift.war//org.apache.commons.discovery.tools.DiscoverSingleton.find(DiscoverSingleton.java:378)
    at deployment.kliftEAR.ear.klift.war//org.apache.axis.components.logger.LogFactory$1.run(LogFactory.java:45)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at deployment.kliftEAR.ear.klift.war//org.apache.axis.components.logger.LogFactory.getLogFactory(LogFactory.java:41)
    at deployment.kliftEAR.ear.klift.war//org.apache.axis.components.logger.LogFactory.(LogFactory.java:33)
    at deployment.kliftEAR.ear.klift.war//org.apache.axis.handlers.BasicHandler.(BasicHandler.java:43)
    at deployment.kliftEAR.ear.klift.war//org.apache.axis.client.Service.getAxisClient(Service.java:104)
    at deployment.kliftEAR.ear.klift.war//org.apache.axis.client.Service.(Service.java:113)
    at deployment.kliftEAR.ear.klift.war//WSSvm.WSSvmServiceLocator.(WSSvmServiceLocator.java:12)
    at deployment.kliftEAR.ear.klift.war//br.com.schmersal.svm.klift2.dao.EstruturaDAO.criarEstruturaTOTVS(EstruturaDAO.java:171)
    at deployment.kliftEAR.ear.klift.war//br.com.schmersal.svm.klift2.controller.antigos.OrcamentoItemPaiController.listaPorOrcamento(OrcamentoItemPaiController.java:94)
    at deployment.kliftEAR.ear.klift.war//br.com.schmersal.svm.klift2.controller.antigos.OrcamentoItemPaiController$Proxy$_$$_WeldClientProxy.listaPorOrcamento(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at deployment.kliftEAR.ear.klift.war//net.vidageek.mirror.provider.java.PureJavaMethodReflectionProvider.invoke(PureJavaMethodReflectionProvider.java:38)
    at deployment.kliftEAR.ear.klift.war//net.vidageek.mirror.invoke.MethodHandlerByMethod.withArgs(MethodHandlerByMethod.java:54)
    at deployment.kliftEAR.ear.klift.war//br.com.caelum.vraptor.core.DefaultReflectionProvider.invoke(DefaultReflectionProvider.java:42)
    at deployment.kliftEAR.ear.klift.war//br.com.caelum.vraptor.core.DefaultReflectionProvider$Proxy$_$$_WeldClientProxy.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at deployment.kliftEAR.ear.klift.war//br.com.caelum.vraptor.observer.ExecuteMethod$1.call(ExecuteMethod.java:82)
    at deployment.kliftEAR.ear.klift.war//br.com.caelum.vraptor.observer.ExecuteMethod$1.call(ExecuteMethod.java:72)
    at deployment.kliftEAR.ear.klift.war//br.com.caelum.vraptor.core.Try.run(Try.java:18)
    at deployment.kliftEAR.ear.klift.war//br.com.caelum.vraptor.observer.ExecuteMethod.execute(ExecuteMethod.java:72)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.jboss.weld.core//org.jboss.weld.injection.StaticMethodInjectionPoint.invoke(StaticMethodInjectionPoint.java:88)
    at org.jboss.weld.core//org.jboss.weld.injection.StaticMethodInjectionPoint.invoke(StaticMethodInjectionPoint.java:78)
    at org.jboss.weld.core//org.jboss.weld.injection.MethodInvocationStrategy$SimpleMethodInvocationStrategy.invoke(MethodInvocationStrategy.java:129)
    at org.jboss.weld.core//org.jboss.weld.event.ObserverMethodImpl.sendEvent(ObserverMethodImpl.java:299)
    at org.jboss.weld.core//org.jboss.weld.event.ObserverMethodImpl.sendEvent(ObserverMethodImpl.java:277)
    at org.jboss.weld.core//org.jboss.weld.event.ObserverMethodImpl.notify(ObserverMethodImpl.java:255)
    at org.jboss.weld.core//org.jboss.weld.event.ObserverNotifier.notifySyncObservers(ObserverNotifier.java:269)
    at org.jboss.weld.core//org.jboss.weld.event.ObserverNotifier.notify(ObserverNotifier.java:258)
    at org.jboss.weld.core//org.jboss.weld.event.EventImpl.fire(EventImpl.java:91)
    at deployment.kliftEAR.ear.klift.war//br.com.caelum.vraptor.core.DefaultInterceptorStack.next(DefaultInterceptorStack.java:78)
    at deployment.kliftEAR.ear.klift.war//br.com.caelum.vraptor.interceptor.ExceptionHandlerInterceptor.intercept(ExceptionHandlerInterceptor.java:75)
    at deployment.kliftEAR.ear.klift.war//br.com.caelum.vraptor.interceptor.ExceptionHandlerInterceptor$Proxy$_$$_WeldClientProxy.intercept(Unknown Source)
    at deployment.kliftEAR.ear.klift.war//br.com.caelum.vraptor.core.ToInstantiateInterceptorHandler$1.call(ToInstantiateInterceptorHandler.java:71)
    at deployment.kliftEAR.ear.klift.war//br.com.caelum.vraptor.core.ToInstantiateInterceptorHandler$1.call(ToInstantiateInterceptorHandler.java:68)
    at deployment.kliftEAR.ear.klift.war//br.com.caelum.vraptor.core.Try.run(Try.java:18)
    at deployment.kliftEAR.ear.klift.war//br.com.caelum.vraptor.core.ToInstantiateInterceptorHandler.executeSafely(ToInstantiateInterceptorHandler.java:68)
    at deployment.kliftEAR.ear.klift.war//br.com.caelum.vraptor.core.ToInstantiateInterceptorHandler.execute(ToInstantiateInterceptorHandler.java:61)
    at deployment.kliftEAR.ear.klift.war//br.com.caelum.vraptor.core.DefaultInterceptorStack.next(DefaultInterceptorStack.java:83)
    at deployment.kliftEAR.ear.klift.war//br.com.caelum.vraptor.interceptor.FlashInterceptor.intercept(FlashInterceptor.java:98)
    at deployment.kliftEAR.ear.klift.war//br.com.caelum.vraptor.interceptor.FlashInterceptor$Proxy$_$$_WeldClientProxy.intercept(Unknown Source)
    at deployment.kliftEAR.ear.klift.war//br.com.caelum.vraptor.core.ToInstantiateInterceptorHandler$1.call(ToInstantiateInterceptorHandler.java:71)
    at deployment.kliftEAR.ear.klift.war//br.com.caelum.vraptor.core.ToInstantiateInterceptorHandler$1.call(ToInstantiateInterceptorHandler.java:68)
    at deployment.kliftEAR.ear.klift.war//br.com.caelum.vraptor.core.Try.run(Try.java:18)
    at deployment.kliftEAR.ear.klift.war//br.com.caelum.vraptor.core.ToInstantiateInterceptorHandler.executeSafely(ToInstantiateInterceptorHandler.java:68)
    at deployment.kliftEAR.ear.klift.war//br.com.caelum.vraptor.core.ToInstantiateInterceptorHandler.execute(ToInstantiateInterceptorHandler.java:61)
    at deployment.kliftEAR.ear.klift.war//br.com.caelum.vraptor.core.DefaultInterceptorStack.next(DefaultInterceptorStack.java:83)
    at deployment.kliftEAR.ear.klift.war//br.com.caelum.vraptor.core.DefaultInterceptorStack$Proxy$_$$_WeldClientProxy.next(Unknown Source)
    at deployment.kliftEAR.ear.klift.war//br.com.caelum.vraptor.interceptor.DefaultSimpleInterceptorStack.next(DefaultSimpleInterceptorStack.java:49)
    at deployment.kliftEAR.ear.klift.war//br.com.caelum.vraptor.interceptor.DefaultSimpleInterceptorStack$Proxy$_$$_WeldClientProxy.next(Unknown Source)
    at deployment.kliftEAR.ear.klift.war//br.com.schmersal.svm.klift2.interceptor.LoginInterceptor.intercept(LoginInterceptor.java:34)
    at deployment.kliftEAR.ear.klift.war//br.com.schmersal.svm.klift2.interceptor.LoginInterceptor$Proxy$_$$_WeldClientProxy.intercept(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at deployment.kliftEAR.ear.klift.war//net.vidageek.mirror.provider.java.PureJavaMethodReflectionProvider.invoke(PureJavaMethodReflectionProvider.java:38)
    at deployment.kliftEAR.ear.klift.war//net.vidageek.mirror.invoke.MethodHandlerByMethod.withArgs(MethodHandlerByMethod.java:54)
    at deployment.kliftEAR.ear.klift.war//br.com.caelum.vraptor.core.DefaultReflectionProvider.invoke(DefaultReflectionProvider.java:42)
    at deployment.kliftEAR.ear.klift.war//br.com.caelum.vraptor.core.DefaultReflectionProvider$Proxy$_$$_WeldClientProxy.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at deployment.kliftEAR.ear.klift.war//br.com.caelum.vraptor.interceptor.StepInvoker.invokeMethod(StepInvoker.java:64)
    at deployment.kliftEAR.ear.klift.war//br.com.caelum.vraptor.interceptor.StepInvoker.tryToInvoke(StepInvoker.java:55)
    at deployment.kliftEAR.ear.klift.war//br.com.caelum.vraptor.interceptor.StepInvoker$Proxy$_$$_WeldClientProxy.tryToInvoke(Unknown Source)
    at deployment.kliftEAR.ear.klift.war//br.com.caelum.vraptor.interceptor.InterceptorExecutor.executeAround(InterceptorExecutor.java:75)
    at deployment.kliftEAR.ear.klift.war//br.com.caelum.vraptor.interceptor.InterceptorExecutor$Proxy$_$$_WeldClientProxy.executeAround(Unknown Source)
    at deployment.kliftEAR.ear.klift.war//br.com.caelum.vraptor.interceptor.AspectStyleInterceptorHandler.execute(AspectStyleInterceptorHandler.java:85)
    at deployment.kliftEAR.ear.klift.war//br.com.caelum.vraptor.core.DefaultInterceptorStack.next(DefaultInterceptorStack.java:83)
    at deployment.kliftEAR.ear.klift.war//br.com.caelum.vraptor.core.DefaultInterceptorStack.start(DefaultInterceptorStack.java:93)
    at deployment.kliftEAR.ear.klift.war//br.com.caelum.vraptor.core.DefaultInterceptorStack$Proxy$_$$_WeldClientProxy.start(Unknown Source)
    at deployment.kliftEAR.ear.klift.war//br.com.caelum.vraptor.observer.RequestHandlerObserver.handle(RequestHandlerObserver.java:93)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.jboss.weld.core//org.jboss.weld.injection.StaticMethodInjectionPoint.invoke(StaticMethodInjectionPoint.java:88)
    at org.jboss.weld.core//org.jboss.weld.injection.StaticMethodInjectionPoint.invoke(StaticMethodInjectionPoint.java:78)
    at org.jboss.weld.core//org.jboss.weld.injection.MethodInvocationStrategy$SimpleMethodInvocationStrategy.invoke(MethodInvocationStrategy.java:129)
    at org.jboss.weld.core//org.jboss.weld.event.ObserverMethodImpl.sendEvent(ObserverMethodImpl.java:299)
    at org.jboss.weld.core//org.jboss.weld.event.ObserverMethodImpl.sendEvent(ObserverMethodImpl.java:277)
    at org.jboss.weld.core//org.jboss.weld.event.ObserverMethodImpl.notify(ObserverMethodImpl.java:255)
    at org.jboss.weld.core//org.jboss.weld.event.ObserverNotifier.notifySyncObservers(ObserverNotifier.java:269)
    at org.jboss.weld.core//org.jboss.weld.event.ObserverNotifier.notify(ObserverNotifier.java:258)
    at org.jboss.weld.core//org.jboss.weld.event.EventImpl.fire(EventImpl.java:91)
    at deployment.kliftEAR.ear.klift.war//br.com.caelum.vraptor.VRaptor.doFilter(VRaptor.java:123)
    at io.undertow.servlet//io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedFilter.doFilter(ManagedFilter.java:61)
    at io.undertow.servlet//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:131)
    at io.undertow.servlet//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler.handleRequest(FilterHandler.java:84)
    at io.undertow.servlet//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletSecurityRoleHandler.handleRequest(ServletSecurityRoleHandler.java:62)
    at io.undertow.servlet//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletDispatchingHandler.handleRequest(ServletDispatchingHandler.java:36)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow//org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.SecurityContextAssociationHandler.handleRequest(SecurityContextAssociationHandler.java:78)
    at io.undertow.core//io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
    at io.undertow.servlet//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.SSLInformationAssociationHandler.handleRequest(SSLInformationAssociationHandler.java:131)
    at io.undertow.servlet//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.handleRequest(ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.java:57)
    at io.undertow.core//io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
    at io.undertow.core//io.undertow.security.handlers.AbstractConfidentialityHandler.handleRequest(AbstractConfidentialityHandler.java:46)
    at io.undertow.servlet//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.handleRequest(ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.java:64)
    at io.undertow.core//io.undertow.security.handlers.AuthenticationMechanismsHandler.handleRequest(AuthenticationMechanismsHandler.java:60)
    at io.undertow.servlet//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.CachedAuthenticatedSessionHandler.handleRequest(CachedAuthenticatedSessionHandler.java:77)
    at io.undertow.core//io.undertow.security.handlers.NotificationReceiverHandler.handleRequest(NotificationReceiverHandler.java:50)
    at io.undertow.core//io.undertow.security.handlers.AbstractSecurityContextAssociationHandler.handleRequest(AbstractSecurityContextAssociationHandler.java:43)
    at io.undertow.core//io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow//org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.jacc.JACCContextIdHandler.handleRequest(JACCContextIdHandler.java:61)
    at io.undertow.core//io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow//org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.GlobalRequestControllerHandler.handleRequest(GlobalRequestControllerHandler.java:68)
    at io.undertow.core//io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
    at io.undertow.servlet//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.handleFirstRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:292)
    at io.undertow.servlet//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.access$100(ServletInitialHandler.java:81)
    at io.undertow.servlet//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$2.call(ServletInitialHandler.java:138)
    at io.undertow.servlet//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$2.call(ServletInitialHandler.java:135)
    at io.undertow.servlet//io.undertow.servlet.core.ServletRequestContextThreadSetupAction$1.call(ServletRequestContextThreadSetupAction.java:48)
    at io.undertow.servlet//io.undertow.servlet.core.ContextClassLoaderSetupAction$1.call(ContextClassLoaderSetupAction.java:43)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow//org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.SecurityContextThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(SecurityContextThreadSetupAction.java:105)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow//org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1508)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow//org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1508)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow//org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1508)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow//org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1508)
    at io.undertow.servlet//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.dispatchRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:272)
    at io.undertow.servlet//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.access$000(ServletInitialHandler.java:81)
    at io.undertow.servlet//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$1.handleRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:104)
    at io.undertow.core//io.undertow.server.Connectors.executeRootHandler(Connectors.java:326)
    at io.undertow.core//io.undertow.server.HttpServerExchange$1.run(HttpServerExchange.java:812)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
    at deployment.kliftEAR.ear.klift.war//org.apache.commons.discovery.tools.DiscoverSingleton.find(DiscoverSingleton.java:426)
    at deployment.kliftEAR.ear.klift.war//org.apache.commons.discovery.tools.DiscoverSingleton.find(DiscoverSingleton.java:378)
    at deployment.kliftEAR.ear.klift.war//org.apache.axis.components.logger.LogFactory$1.run(LogFactory.java:45)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at deployment.kliftEAR.ear.klift.war//org.apache.axis.components.logger.LogFactory.getLogFactory(LogFactory.java:41)
    at deployment.kliftEAR.ear.klift.war//org.apache.axis.components.logger.LogFactory.(LogFactory.java:33)
    ... 126 more
Caused by: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException
    at org.jboss.logmanager.commons.logging//org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory.getClassLoader(LogFactory.java:401)
    at deployment.kliftEAR.ear.klift.war//org.apache.commons.logging.impl.LogFactoryImpl.getClassLoader(LogFactoryImpl.java:447)
    at deployment.kliftEAR.ear.klift.war//org.apache.commons.logging.impl.LogFactoryImpl.initDiagnostics(LogFactoryImpl.java:476)
    at deployment.kliftEAR.ear.klift.war//org.apache.commons.logging.impl.LogFactoryImpl.(LogFactoryImpl.java:95)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at deployment.kliftEAR.ear.klift.war//org.apache.commons.discovery.tools.ClassUtils.newInstance(ClassUtils.java:157)
    at deployment.kliftEAR.ear.klift.war//org.apache.commons.discovery.tools.SPInterface.newInstance(SPInterface.java:197)
    at deployment.kliftEAR.ear.klift.war//org.apache.commons.discovery.tools.DiscoverClass.newInstance(DiscoverClass.java:579)
    at deployment.kliftEAR.ear.klift.war//org.apache.commons.discovery.tools.DiscoverSingleton.find(DiscoverSingleton.java:418)
    ... 131 more
```

Comment: Try with java 8, to see if you can reproduce it.

Answer (score 4):

Wildfly 11 change the logging modules in relation to Wildfly 10.

Try to recovery Wildfly 10 logging configuration in this way:

**1. Copy "jcl-over-slf4j" module from Wildfly 10 to Wildfly 11**

> cd /opt/wildfly-11.0.0.Final/modules/system/layers/base/org/slf4j
>
> cp -R
> /opt/wildfly-10.1.0.Final/modules/system/layers/base/org/slf4j/jcl-over-slf4j .

**2. Go to the Wildfly 11 load logging module**

> cd /opt/wildfly-11.0.0.Final/modules/system/layers/base/org/apache/commons/logging/main

**3. Load new module instead Wildfly 11 default**

> vi module.xml
>
> Replace `<module name="org.jboss.logmanager.commons.logging" export="true"/>`
>
> With `<module name="org.slf4j.jcl-over-slf4j" export="true"/>`

This works for me.

---

PD: If you dont have Wildfly 10 available you could try this:

> cd /opt/wildfly-11.0.0.Final/modules/system/layers/base/org/slf4j
>
> mkdir  jcl-over-slf4j
>
> mkdir main
>
> cd jcl-over-slf4j/main
>
> vi module.xml

and in the new file copy this:

```
<module xmlns="urn:jboss:module:1.3" name="org.slf4j.jcl-over-slf4j">
     <properties>
         <property name="jboss.api" value="private"/>
     </properties>

    <resources>
        <resource-root path="jcl-over-slf4j-1.7.7.jar"/>
    </resources>

    <dependencies>
        <module name="org.slf4j"/>
    </dependencies>
</module>
```

Finally, download jcl-over-slf4j-1.7.7.jar and move to the same directory than module.xml

Answer (score 2):

There was a similar error in JBoss EAP server. The reason is library conflict between **commons-logging.jar** bundled in war and the module **org.apache.commons.logging** in EAP server. Resolution was to add a file **jboss-deployment-structure.xml** in **WEB-INF** folder with the following content. This will exclude the server org.apache.commons.logging library and include the commons-logging.jar library included in the war.

```
<jboss-deployment-structure>
    <deployment>
        <exclusions>
            <module name="org.apache.commons.logging" />
        </exclusions>
    </deployment>
</jboss-deployment-structure>
```

Answer (score 1):

This was fixed in [[WFCORE-3389] Upgrade commons-logging-jboss-logmanager from 1.0.2.Final to 1.0.3.Final - JBoss Issue Tracker](https://issues.jboss.org/browse/WFCORE-3389).

You can resolve updating the commons-logging-jboss-logmanager Wildfly module to version 1.0.3.Final, in $WILDFLY_HOME/modules/system/layers/base/org/jboss/logmanager/commons/logging/main diretory.

Reference: [JBoss Developer Forum](https://developer.jboss.org/thread/277288)

Answer (score 0):

We saw a similar error when upgrading from WildFly 10 to WildFly 11. It seemed related to the presence of the commons-logging.jar in our webapp. You might try removing that jar and see that you're configured to use the WildFly-provided builtin logging module. I believe that module provides a working commons-logging API.

We solved our problem differently because our web apps don't use the builtin logging module. We had previously disabled logging for all apps:

```
    <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:logging:3.0">
        <!-- allow modules to use alternate logging subsystem -->
        <add-logging-api-dependencies value="false"/>
        <use-deployment-logging-config value="false"/>
```

We then had a custom module with Log4J jars. That module includes the commons logging bridge log4j-jcl.jar, which then redirected the commons-logging API to log4j 2.